# Can a Union have another column name as long as the number of columns is the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a query I would like to eventually put into a view.

First can I name my Flag column differently as long as I have 2 columns throughout?

Also, can I perform a union on the same table with a different WHERE clause?

Finally, what is the correct approach for getting these 3 selects into 1 view?

```
    SELECT ID, 'Y' AS PW_CHANGE31, NULL AS LAST_LOGON90, NULL AS LAST_LOGON365 FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Password Change] < GETDATE() - 31)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NULL AS PW_CHANGE31, 'Y' AS LAST_LOGON90, NULL AS LAST_LOGON365 FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 90) AND ([Account Disabled] = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NULL AS PW_CHANGE31, NULL AS LAST_LOGON90, 'Y' AS LAST_LOGON365 FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 365)
```

**UPDATED TO:

```
SELECT ID, '31' AS StatusVal FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Password Change] < GETDATE() - 31)
UNION 
SELECT ID, '90' AS StatusVal FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 90) AND ([Account Disabled] = 0)
UNION 
SELECT ID, '365' AS StatusVal FROM user_info WITH (nolock) WHERE ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 365)
```

Comment: @JoJo - I'm not sure about having column names different. I think it will work, but not sure what the resulting column name is.  I would recommend aliasing each to be sure.  I do want to point out that UNION will do a distinct on your rows.  If you don't want that to occur, then you need to do a "UNION ALL" to preserve all rows in your three queries when putting them together.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it will work, I've even seen this on one of the msdn exams, I can't remember the exact behavior but either the first or last wins as being the column name.

Comment: "Finally, what is the correct approach for getting these 3 selects into 1 view?" Once you have your final query how you want it, you will just need to learn how to use CREATE VIEW in your mysql database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: @JoJo - your updated query pulling out status codes is a big improvement.

Comment: Another tip: I've had cases where it had trouble with the data type when the column had a hard coded NULL.  So suggest you cast each null, like CAST(NULL as Varchar(50)) as myColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized what you are doing with this query.  I think instead of having 3 rows for the same person (which is a potential result) with the UNION approach, you probably want 1 row per user with the 3 flags set with the proper values.  Note: I did not run this query, there may be syntax errors.

```
SELECT u.ID,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(u1.id) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END CASE AS PW_CHANGE31,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(u2.id) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END CASE AS LAST_LOGON90,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(u3.id) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END CASE AS LAST_LOGON365
FROM user_info u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info u1 on u.id = u1.id 
        AND ([Last Password Change] < GETDATE() - 31)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info u2 on u.id = u2.id
        AND ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 90) AND ([Account Disabled] = 0)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info u3 on u.id = u3.id
        AND ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 365)
WHERE u1.id IS NOT NULL
    OR u2.id IS NOT NULL
    OR u3.id IS NOT NULL
```

I tried to keep the same three subqueries in tact above so you could see the structure.  I think you should eliminate the joins altogether and just do the arithmetic in the CASE statements like this:

```
SELECT u.ID,
    CASE WHEN ([Last Password Change] < GETDATE() - 31) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END CASE AS PW_CHANGE31,
    CASE WHEN (([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 90) AND ([Account Disabled] = 0)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END CASE AS LAST_LOGON90,
    CASE WHEN ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 365) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END CASE AS LAST_LOGON365
FROM user_info u
WHERE ([Last Password Change] < GETDATE() - 31)
    OR (([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 90) AND ([Account Disabled] = 0))
    OR ([Last Logon] < GETDATE() - 365)
```

Again, these queries may have syntax errors, but I think gets you a better performing query along with the fact that you will only have one row per user with flags set correctly.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That will work as long as all three columns are type compatible. The name only matters in so far as the result column will be called PW_CHANGE31 which may end up being confusing. In general I'd alias it .